# Navigation/View flow with MVC in the context of a C++ desktop application

Tags: c++, model-view-controller

Let's imagine you have a fullscreen C++ desktop application that consists of several screens with each of them having a distinct function and a ViewController with appropriate models as well. For example a set of the following very simplified screens:

1. Quiz: The user is navigated through a set of multiple-choice questions.
2. Quiz Results with Statistics.
3. Information: The user is presented with information about a specific subject.
4. Menu (Quiz, Information, Exit)

Judging by the GRASP principle *Information Expert*, each ViewController will know best when it is finished and time to move to a new screen. Yet by the same principle, it is not the right place to decide what the next screen should actually be. In this rather simple example, one could argue it would be okay but in a more complex application, it will undoubtedly lead to duplicated code and logic as well as higher coupling and lower cohesion. There is also the problem that you would have to create the new widget and controller within the current screen's ViewController which brings all sorts of new problems and at least by the *Creator* principle, it is not the right choice. You would have to introduce a Factory to alleviate some of the problems, amongst other things.

So, the next logical step is to introduce an ApplicationController with the sole responsibility of managing Views and their controllers including the navigation flow from one view to the next.

This still leaves one problem wide open in my opinion: How to signal the ApplicationController that it is time to move to a different screen and hand over the control to that object properly?

One could use the Observer pattern, for example. Yet what if you have an expensive View active at the moment and want that one destroyed once the new screen is active? If the current ViewController signals the ApplicationController that the next screen should go up, it can manage everything up to the point where it would destroy the currently active screen which it cannot do because the current call comes from exactly that object. Apart from several other problems with that approach.

So my question is (and sorry for all the verbose introduction :P): How do you properly implement a navigation flow from one fullscreen widget to a different one with MVC which solves the above problems, splits the responsibility between the View- and ApplicationController and is nicely object oriented in terms of coupling and cohesion?

Comment: Silly me, I did not notice I was logged in serverfault. :( Sorry for that. Could someone move the question over to the appropriate site? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you miss one detail in your thought process and you open up a whole can of problems without even realizing the mistake you made.

In this case the detail was that you can naturally post asynchronous as well as synchronous events. If you have to make sure that you are no longer in the context of the event posting method, post an asynchronous event. Once you receive that event in your handler, you can be sure that the context was left. And for example you can safely delete the object, if you so desire. Naturally the event handler should not be in the context of the same object that you are trying to delete.

For completeness: In Qt, you can specify for each signal/slot-connection you make with connect(), that it should be of type Qt::QueuedConnection. If you raise a signal, it won't be delivered until the control is back to the thread's event loop. Normally, Qt::AutoConnection is used which delivers a signal at the time it is raised (Qt::DirectConnection) if the receiver is in the same thread or falls back to queuing that signal (Qt::QueuedConnection) if the receiver is in a different thread.

In wxWidgets you can queue events with wxEvtHandler::QueueEvent(wxEvent* event) which is available through the Application singleton for example.